# using GFAPI::submit_form to submit a checkbox with multiple options

Tags: gravity-forms-plugin, gravityforms

I'm trying to use the Gravity Forms API to submit a set of checkboxes programmatically, the values of the checkboxes on the form that is being submitted are "By Email", "By Post" and "By SMS" and the ID of the checkbox field is 40.
Along with the other fields (these all submit properly) i'm passing the following set of data to GFAPI::submit_form , no validation errors occur on running this code, however the values are not shown in the entries area of gravity forms, does anybody know if this is the correct syntax for a set of checkboxes to submit?

```
    $input_values[input_40_1] => By Email
    $input_values[input_40_2] => By Post
    $input_values[input_40_3] => By SMS

$result = GFAPI::submit_form(54, $input_values);
```

Answer (score 0):

Turned out this was an issue with a mismatch in the database schema for the two fields, the data inside of them was the same but saved in a different format (the likely explanation for this was the forms being created in differing versions of Gravity forms)

To fix we copied the field_meta from the field in the new form, changed the IDs to match the one in the old form and inserted it over the field in the old form